# TextField getCharBoundaries not giving proper co-ordinates

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, textfield

I'm developing one AS3 application in which I need to add blank editable box between string. I use  tag to define blank. The problem I'm having is, getCharBoundries may b not giving proper bounding box for characters. to get boundingBox of word, I use getCharBourndries of First char of word and last char of word and calculate x, y and width of it. but as u see in below image, more characters blank has, last character spills out.

[image]

Any Help guys?

Comment: Posting the relevant code would be helpful.  It is most likely something in your calculation that is throwing it off.

Comment: Can't you figure out the position of each character with startPosition + letterIndex * deltaPixelsForEachLetter ?

Comment: Nevermind, I guess not all letters have the same width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is there a way to get the actual bounding box of a glyph in ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942911/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-actual-bounding-box-of-a-glyph-in-actionscript)

Answer (score 2):

Add a delay before you use the getCharBoundries method, TextFields take frame initialize.

TweenLite has a nice delay call:

```
TweenLite.delayedCall(1, _delayFunction);
```