# how to calculate boundary rectangle of text with cotillion font style?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, air, flex4

while working with font of **cotillion style** when calculating **get bounds** of text/texts.getBounds() doesn't give correct result, it consider text mid point as  Bottom_left point of that resultant rectangle.

please help me in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Is there a way to get the actual bounding box of a glyph in ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942911/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-actual-bounding-box-of-a-glyph-in-actionscript/1943007#1943007) -- it seems to describe the inverse (too *much* space around characters), but trust me: it's the same issue. Check if the suggestions in that post can solve yours.

Characters are designed on a square grid, and it's the responsibility of the font designer to make sure that *characters do not touch*. This is done by leaving a small area of white space around the design. The bottom left of this box is its "bottom-left point", or, more accurately, the *origin* of the character. The total width of the box is the *advance width* of the character -- the amount the cursor needs to move right.

Usually, there is only empty space around a character. After all, you would not like a font that bunches all characters up to each other. There are a few exceptions, though. A space character, for example, only has width -- no image. A "non-spacing" accent has a *negative* width, so if you type an `e` followed by a non-spacing `"`, you get what appears to be an `ë`. And, of course, it could be a design decision to have characters overlap.

How does this relate to your "cotillion" ("script") font? Well, the curves and line ends *need* to stick "out of the box" -- if they do not, and the box was large enough to encompass each entire character, you would get large and uneven spacing between the characters.

Apparently, `getBounds` only calculates the advance width of your text -- and for a perfectly good reason! In almost every application of fonts, the advance width is the only one that counts. So `getBounds` does not return a *wrong* value, it returns exactly what it was designed to do.

To get the exact area, you could try to use the low-level functions of your text engine ([FreeType](http://www.freetype.org) has functions for this), or use the tricks mentioned in the linked post: convert to outlines and measure these, or draw inside a bitmap and check the pixel coverage.